# about "scripts" key in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, npm, package.json

Can anyone explain what is the purpose of "scripts" key in package.json file.

While learning Angular 2 , I came across below script in package.json file,
was not sure whats the use of this key.

```
"scripts": {
"postinstall": "npm run typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"start": "concurrent \"node ./bin/www\" \"npm run tsc:w\"",
"typings" : "typings"
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scripts` key provides a convenient place to define project-specific automation scripts right there in your already-mandatory `package.json`. This helps developers just type something simple, like `npm run cover` or `npm run deploy` and have a possibly-complex series of steps (with very specific file locations or program arguments) kicked off. This avoids typing long command lines, and it avoids errors. For example, one of my projects includes these commands:

```
"scripts": {
    "cover": "cd source/js/jutil && istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec && open coverage/lcov-report/jutil/index.html",
    "test": "cd source/js/jutil && mocha",
    "deploy": "(git diff --quiet --exit-code --cached || git commit -a -m 'deploy') && git push heroku master && heroku open",
    "start": "gulp start"
}
```

I can quickly run a test, a coverage test, or deploy to a cloud host with just a few words, and never having to remember the detailed command-line options or file locations.

Beware, however. There is much controversy in the JavaScript / node.js community about the "best" or "right" place to define such automation.

Many developers prefer to shift automation to separate "task runners" / "build systems" such as [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), or even good ole Unix `make`. For those projects, the `scripts` tag will be empty or nearly so. (`npm init` by default generates at least a single key, for `test`.) Instead you need to look to their `gulpfile.js`, `Gruntfile`, or `Makefile`.

Other developers have rejected the idea of becoming build-system mechanics and/or separating out build configuration. They often prefer to put "a few simple scripts" directly in `package.json` and call it a day.

In my experience, "a few simple commands" is a great goal but scripting complexity can quickly outstrip it. This is especially true in larger projects with many different assets and asset types, for which live-rebuild or live-reload are desired, or that have more than a few deployment options. I usually end up with `gulp` doing the heavy-lifting, but perhaps a few scripts that can truly be concisely stated still resident in `package.json`. "Your mileage may vary."

Answer (score 1):

Refer this, it will give you a better idea [script in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).